# What is the significance of the intersection of an isothermal and adibatic curve?

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: isothermal and adiabatic curves on a p-v diagram]

On a p-v Diagram the adiabatic and isothermal intersect at a point. What does it signify?

Comment: It means that they both pass through the same thermodynamic equilibrium state.  So.....

Comment: *Every* point on a $PV$ diagram has an adiabat and an isotherm passing through it, so unless this particular adiabat and isotherm mean something special it does not mean anything in particular.

Comment: Frankly, there is nothing significant about it. Many different processes intersect. Perhaps there is more to your question(?)

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, it signifies the fact that adiabatic curves drop faster than isothermal curves (for ideal gas: $P=\frac {const} V$ for isothermal processes and $P=\frac {const} {V^\gamma}$, where $\gamma > 1$, for adiabatic processes) and, as a result, any adiabatic curve will cross any isothermal curve exactly at one point.

Comment: Just a minor point. Instead of the statement that "any adiabatic curve will cross any isothermal curve exactly at one point" I would suggest the statement,"for any given adiabatic curve you can find at least one isothermal curve where they cross at exactly one point, and vice-versa". A specific isothermal curve and specific adiabatic curve with defined initial and final states, may not intersect.

Comment: @BobD Thanks for your comment. I actually wanted to make a statement as general as possible, which, without imposing initial and final states, should be valid.

Comment: Got it and I agree

Comment: By the way, the situation of convexity and unique intersections is *much* more general than just ideal gases and cuts to a core principle of statistical mechanics: decomposability. David Mukamel has some great lectures on statistical mechanics with long range interactions where this assumption (and hence convexity of the free energy) breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply that P and V are uniquely determined once you know S and T. The precise way to determine it depends on the equation of state.

By the way, in general there are $2n + 1$ thermodynamic variables and $n$ of them determine the state, and the uniqueness of the intersection point follows from convexity of the graphs, which follows from local interactions.